# Converting Poloniex API Callback JSON into format suitable for Highcharts.Stockchart

Tags: javascript, json, api, highcharts, poloniex

I am trying to get JSON from [Poloniex's](https://poloniex.com/support/api/) public API method (specifically the returnChartData method) to display chart history of cryptocurrencies against one another into a Highchart Stockchart graph (looking like the [demo one here.](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/members/chart-destroy/)).

This is part of my JavaScript code to use the Poloniex returnChartData callback, get the JSON from it and implement it into the 'data' segment of the chart. So far it is not working and I can't for the life of me figure out what I need to change.

```
var poloniexUrl = "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_XMR&start=1405699200&end=9999999999&period=14400";
$.getJSON(poloniexUrl, function(data){
  results = data;
});
// Creates Chart
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({


chart: {
 renderTo: 'cryptoChart',
 backgroundColor: 'white'
},

title: {
  text: currentTitle
},

series: [{
  data: results,
  turboThreshold: 1000
}],

xAxis: {
 original: false
},

rangeSelector: {
 selected: 1
},

plotOptions: {
 line: {
  gapSize: 2
 }
}
});
```

Would love any help!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this **live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/0f4odg5q/

If you use `turboThreshold` the points' options need to be given as an integer or an array (**Explanation:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold). In your case the format is JSON, so I disabled `turboThreshold` to prevent **Higcharts error 12** (https://www.highcharts.com/errors/12):

```
  turboThreshold: 0
```

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous - the best way to make sure that `data` variable is initialized is using it inside callback function (second argument of `getJSON`):

```
$.getJSON(poloniexUrl, function(data) {

  // Creates Chart
  var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
    (...)
```

The data that you fetch looks like candlestick series - I changed the type of the series:

```
  type: 'candlestick'
```

Date will be properly understood by Highcharts if it's kept in the `x` property of JSON object (not `date`):

```
  data: data.map((p) => {
    p.x = p.date;
    return p
  }),
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil! If I try to re-call that function though (say with the press of a button on my page) it comes with an error saying data.map is not a function- do you know wht this would be?

Comment: Could you provide a live working demo of this issue?